# How to add object to queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

my sample code is :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    ....
```

I want do some thing like this in view :

```
user = User.objects.none()

categories = Category.objects.filter(**filter)

for category in categories:

    # my problem is here , how add user category object to queryset
    # or merge object and queryset
    user = user | category.user
```

this part of code is for showing problem :

```
    user = user | category.user
```

thanx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. A Queryset is a container for objects that satisfy a query, hence the name. It's not a container for arbitrary objects.

Here the correct thing to do is to query the users you need directly. You can follow the relationship to the Category object by using the double-underscore syntax:

```
users = User.objects.filter(category__criteria=value)
```

Comment: I need find the way with best performance ,that`s costly to do some thing like this.
but thanx